# How to determine if something is part of a big Oh function?

Tags: performance, algorithm, math

I've been working on this homework for about 4 hours, and I've managed to figure out a few of the questions on this, but I still have no idea what this one is talking about:

Which of the following are true and which are false, and why?

(a) √n^5 ∈ O(n^2)

(b) √n log √n ∈ O(n)

(c) log(n^3) ∈ O(n log n)

(d) 2/n + 4/n^2 ∈ Θ(1/n)

(e) (log_2(n))^.5 ∈ Θ(log(n))

(f) min(700, n^2) ∈ Θ(1)

My understanding is that I'm supposed to take f(n)/g(n) and put it in the limit as n-> infinity, and solve.. but that is giving me 0 for every single one of them, and I know that isn't right.

How do I do this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Actually, that seems right. Are you sure all of these are supposed to be Big Oh? I see a few Big Thetas there...

Comment: Marcin: I'm supposed to be determining whether these statements are true or false, and yeah, the last 3 are thetas (in other words, they have to be big O() of each other for it to be true, instead of just f being big O(g()))

Thanks

Comment: Do you know the definition of Theta? You know what Big Oh is about, do you still have some problem with this assignment?

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to determine if any of these are true or false. I've tried solving it and I get the same value for each question, which I know can't be right.

Comment: Well, apart from (e) they are all correct. Since you 'tried solving it' and got some result, you apparently do know how to determine it, but you doubt correctness of your solution.

Comment: @MarcinŁoś, if by  “correct” you mean true, I disagree that  “apart from (e) they are all correct”.   (a) is false, (b)-(f) true.

Comment: @jwpat7 I may be a bit rusty at math, but I'm not sure (b) or (c) are true, either. e.g. `log(n^3) == 3 log(n) == O(log(n))` is not `O(n log(n))`...

Comment: @twalberg, regarding (b), log √n = (log n)/2 < √n for n≥1 so √n log √n ≤ √n·√n = n.  Regarding (c), log(n) is not θ(n log(n)), but it is in O(log(n)) and O(n) and O(n log(n)), etc.  However, MarcinŁoś *is* right that (e) is false; I overlooked the θ in (e); it would be true with O instead of θ, but is not true with θ.  BTW, for (a), √n^5 = n²√n > n²

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions related to programming. This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics or theoretical computer science, each of which has a dedicated site on the Stackexchange network; see the list of links at the bottom of the page. In any case you should show the work you have done, for example, do you know the definitions of big-O and big-theta?

Comment: @jwpat7 Ah, yes, my bad... I tend to forget that `O()` is simply an upper bound, not a minimal upper bound...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are two ways you can think of this.  One is the way you represented, f(n)/g(n), as n-> infinity, the value approaches 0.  Or the way I think is easier:

```
There is some pair of constants A and B such that A * g(n) + B > f(n) for all n.
```

This better represents what Big-O notation represents, and that is that one functions growth consumes another functions growth.  This also happens to be a representation of big-o notation that is easily checked using a graphing calculator, to confirm your answers :).

You can usually ignore the B value, and just make sure that A*g(n) grows faster than f(n).  The B is just a formality.